# free moving bike in gear

Tags: engine, motorcycle, starting, yamaha

I am using **Yamaha FZ**. Sometimes in morning, the bike is not start with electric as well as kick start. When i put it in gears and tried to move the bike, it will move like neutral gear. If I move the bike long with gear the friction inside the engine become increase and engine may starts.

**What is this issue?**

**How can we repair this issue?**

Model : 2012

Engine type : Air cooled, 4-stroke, SOHC, 2-valve

Displacement : 153.0cc

Bore & Stroke : 58.0mm x 57.9mm

Compression ratio : 9.5 : 1

Maximum output : 14PS@ 7500 rpm

Maximum torque : 13.6 Nm @6000 rpm

Starting method : Electric and kick

Lubrication type : Wet Sump

Fuel Supply : Carburetor

Clutch type : Wet, multiple-disc

Primary/secondary reduction ratio : 3.409 / 2.857

Transmission type : Constant mesh 5-speed

Gear ratio : 1st=2.714 2nd=1.789 3rd=1.318 4th=1.045 5th=0.875

Cylinder layout : Forward-inclined Single Cylinder

Battery : 12V, 5.0AH

Comment: What is the engine size in your FZ? What year is the bike?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 153cc around 15hp commuter motorcycle

Comment: I believe that your motorcycle has a one way sprag clutch.  This is most likely your failure point.  When the attacks on internet ease up you can likely verify this and even find some videos on how it works.  Failure is likely the sprags themselves or the gears driving the inner or outer ring.